# Punctuating a Sentence Containing a Question

Tags: punctuation, questions, question-mark, periods

If a sentence contains a complete question, but ends with a statement, should it be punctuated with a question mark?

Example:

> Could she go to the store, he wondered

Comment: What Drm65 says; and a question mark at the end of your sentence would not be right, though people often do that. Whether or not a sentence should end with a question mark depends on whether the main clause is a question; subordinate clauses or other units do not matter.

Comment: "To be or not to be: that is the question." Your sentence is fine as is, with no question mark.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you do not want to put the question in quotes, as if the character were saying it, thus:

> "Could she go to the store?" he wondered.

If you want to describe him thinking, then you could put the thought in italics:

> *Could she go to the store?* he wondered.

Or you could rephrase the sentence:

> He wondered if she could go to the store.

It is always possible to rearrange/reformat a sentence to avoid putting a question mark where you don't want it, as well as avoid saying a question with no question mark.