# Assertive clause with comma followed by an interrogative

Tags: commas, questions

Can we write in the following manner? A complete question is embedded in an assertive sentence separated by a comma:
**He thought, how can I complete this task?**

Comment: You should give some idea of the context in which this is said, and explain why you have not written *He thought, "How can I complete this task?"*

Comment: 'He thought' is better seen as a speech tag subclass thought. Your particular question is addressed at [How to punctuate a question within a thought](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137713/how-to-punctuate-a-question-within-a-thought) and answered at [Punctuating a sentence containing a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/punctuating-a-sentence-containing-a-question).